# Principal component analysis of dichotomous variables

Tags: r, pca, psych

I am trying to carry out a principal component analysis of dichotomous variables (latent continuous scale) on individuals belonging to two groups, to see if such groups differ with respect to principal components. Since there is a latent continuous scale underneath your binary data, I used tetrachoric correlation. Here is an example of the data I am working with

```
df <- data.frame(CMS_1 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_2 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_3 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_4 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_5 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_6 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_7 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_8 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_9 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_10 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_11 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_12 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_13 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              CMS_14 = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1,
              disease_status = sample(2, replace = T, size = 10)-1)
```

"CMS_1:CMS_14" are the dichotomous variables I am interested in extracting principal components from. "disease_status" denotes group membership, i.e. whether a subjects has the disease or not. Here is the code to produce principal components from tetrachoric correlation matrix.

```
library(psych)

library(factoextra)

library(FactoMineR)

df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, as.factor)

df_matrix<-data.matrix(df[,-15])

df_tetra<-tetrachoric(df_matrix)

res.pca <- PCA(df_tetra$rho, graph = FALSE)
```

If I insepct "res.pca", it says:

**Results for the Principal Component Analysis (PCA)**
The analysis was performed on 14 individuals, described by 14 variables

I am interested in extracting results for individuals, to see if the groups such individuals belong to contribute differently to the principal components. The function get_pca_ind() and fviz_pca_ind() from factoextra would do if I passed the original dataset (df) to the function PCA(). However, since I used the tetrachoric correlation matrix the same set of variables (CMS_1:CSM_14) are treated as individuals. In fact, as I wrote above, inspecting the results from PCA() on tetrachoric correaltion matrix brings: The analysis was performed on 14 individuals, described by 14 variables. Thanks!